Obtener el tipo de cambio del UYU desde la API
La consigna es escribir un programa en C que dada una cantidad en pesos uruguayos, obtenga la equivalencia en dólares. El funcionamiento consiste en conectarse a una página web, capturar la unidad cambiaria y efectuar las operaciones correspondientes para realizar la conversión de moneda.
Para dicha captura tengo esta función que pretende extraer el tipo de cambio de la siguiente página https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD y lo devuelve como un valor. El problema es que por alguna razón que desconozco no puede capturar el valor de la unidad cambiaria de la dicha url
Secuencia:

La función obtenerTipoDeCambio se conecta con el sitio https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD, busca dónde dice "UYU":

Una vez conectado al sitio, se posiciona a la derecha "mira" hacia la derecha, captura el valor (a la fecha 1 de diciembre de 2024 a las 00:02:31 es de 42.821491), y retorna ese valor al main.

Con ese valor obtenido, el main hace la simple división entre la unidad cambiaria obtenida y el valor en pesos que ingresa el usuario.

Finalmente se muestra el valor de la división en pantalla
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Estructura para almacenar la respuesta HTTP
struct string {
    char *ptr;
    size_t len;
};

// Inicializar estructura string
void init_string(struct string *s) {
    s->len = 0;
    s->ptr = malloc(s->len + 1);
    if (s->ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s->ptr[0] = '\0';
}

// Callback para recibir datos
size_t writefunc(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct string *s) {
    size_t new_len = s->len + size * nmemb;
    s->ptr = realloc(s->ptr, new_len + 1);
    if (s->ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memcpy(s->ptr + s->len, ptr, size * nmemb);
    s->ptr[new_len] = '\0';
    s->len = new_len;

    return size * nmemb;
}

// Función para obtener el tipo de cambio
float obtenerTipoDeCambio() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct string s;
    float tipo_cambio = -1.0; // Valor por defecto en caso de error

    // Inicializar CURL
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        init_string(&s);

        // Configurar la solicitud HTTP
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);

        // Realizar la solicitud
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        // Verificar si hubo errores
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        } else {
            // Extraer el tipo de cambio para UYU
            char *uyu_pos = strstr(s.ptr, "\"UYU\":");
            if (uyu_pos) {
                char *valor_inicio = strchr(uyu_pos, ':');
                if (valor_inicio) {
                    tipo_cambio = strtof(valor_inicio + 1, NULL); // Convertir a float
                }
            }
        }

        // Limpiar
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        free(s.ptr);
    }

    return tipo_cambio; // Retornar el tipo de cambio o -1 en caso de error
}

    int main(){
    .
    .
    .
    }




" por alguna razón que desconozco no puede capturar el valor".. hay un error? no encuentra la clave en la pagina? o sea.. que es lo que pasa? que hay que mirar y buscar???

El programa debería poder encontrar la cadena UYU en la página web, fijarse que valor tiene, tomarlo, retornar ese valor main y hacer la división con el valor en pesos dado por el usuario. El problema es que no puede encontrar la cadena UYU.

Y como esta esa cadena? y lo que devuelve lo contiene? como lo contiene? faltan como un monton de cosas a la pregunta para que te podamos ayudar....

¿Entiendes el código que posteé ¿Leíste la consigna?

Ahí agregué más información para que quede más claro la consigna.

Y qué cosas sabes que funcionan bien? Se obtiene bien el JSON?

No sé si es un problema de la url, de sitio o un error de función. Por eso pregunto.
